# how to retrieve data from incoming message in blackberry 5.0

Tags: blackberry

could any one please help us to retrieve data from incoming message in blackberry 8520 and to store the retrived data in to the shared preferences

Comment: Who gave u up vote? We can't get sms's in simulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the listener to listen the messages before coming into the inbox. But you cannot read the messages that are already received. You can use the below sample code:

```
try{    
dc = (DatagramConnection) Connector.open("sms://");
        for(;;){
            if(stop){
                return;
            }
            Datagram d = dc.newDatagram(dc.getMaximumLength());
            dc.receive(d);
            String address = new String(d.getAddress());
            String msg = new String(d.getData());
            MyScreen.update(msg,address);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println(e.toString());
    }
```

You can find more information BlackBerry_Application_Developer_Guide_Volume_1 book